# How do you declare a method as public but non-static in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

The question is in the title.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks! I'll update the question to address that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are non-static by default:

```
public function method() {

}
```

You will get an `E_STRICT` if you call it statically, but I don't think you can easily enforce that it can only be called on an instance - <strike>if you try to check `$this` I think you will get an error.</strike> You could do `isset($this)` as Artefacto says and throw an exception if it isn't set.

Comment: You can throw an exception if `isset($this)` is `false`.

Comment: This can still be called as a static function.

Comment: @Artefacto Have you seen any code doing this explicitly in all non-static methods? That looks cumbersome. Hopefully you will get some sort of error inside the method if $this is not set.

Comment: @Artefacto: thanks, tested and updated it. for some reason i thought that would fail.

Comment: @Alex Yes, you get a fatal error if you use `$this` in a static context, which most non-static functions will do (if they don't access the instance, I suppose they could be static instead).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class abc() {

 public function foo() {
     ...
 }
}

$c = new abc();
$c->foo();
?>
```

Comment: foo() would still be available through abc::foo().

Comment: yes that's true. I don't know another way to do it. Function is public and object oriented (means that's a method)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class abc() {

 public function foo() {
     if (!isset($this)) {
         throw new Exception('Method is non-static.');
         exit();
     }
 }
}

$c = new abc();
$c->foo();
?>
```

Not tested.